# CodeMirror firing own events with 'signal'

Tags: javascript, jquery, codemirror

I am currently learning how to implement the `showHint` function in CodeMirror. I am using this [example](https://codemirror.net/demo/xmlcomplete.html) as a guideline of learning. However, I do not get how `signal` actually works in this context (show-hint.js - line 45).

```
CodeMirror.signal(this, "startCompletion", this);
```

As far as I understand, it fires the event handler named `startCompletion` in CodeMirror. However, I don't seem to find any such event being created. Can someone please enlighten me on this?

Answer (score 0):

That line is all it takes to 'create' the event. It'll look for handlers (registered on the editor with the `on` method) for the `"startCompletion"` event and call them.

Comment: I searched the whole project but can't find "startCompletion" being called anywhere. Can you guide me?

Comment: The line you quoted will call it. Try the [docs](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#events).